# How could I connect MySQL Server (on a EC2 ) from another EC2?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mysql-cluster

I create two instances on EC2 (CentOS 7). I am trying to deploy MySQL InnoDB Cluster. When I add instance (`slave`) I found master cannot be connected.

I can use GUI tool on my local to connect the master, but I cannot use mysql cli to connect slave from master. I have close firewalld and iptables, I also disable SELINUX. My security group is open all traffic. I don't know what else should I check. Hope someone could help me fix this issue.

Here is my error：

```
[root@ip-172-31-25-217 centos]# mysql -u root -p -h node2 -P 3306
Enter password:
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'node2' (110)
```

Comment: Does it locate within the same VPC and region? Can you ping the second node from the master? Have you tried to use IP instead of FQDN?

Comment: @Strepsils Yes, master and slave are at same region and VPC. They can ping each other. I also have set `root@%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a *Security Group* issue.

Make sure both EC2 instances are in the same **Security Group** and make sure that the SG permits traffic to TCP port 3306 from members of the same group.

To do that go to EC2 console ➡ Instances and select your instance. Inspect what's under *Security Groups* in the details and if they have the same SGs attached. If they don't change it through Actions (at the top) ➡ Networking ➡ **Change Security Groups**.

Next check that the SG permits access to tcp/3306 from all the members of that SG. Let's say the group id is `sg-1234abcd` - you can find the real SG ID in the *Group ID* column.

Click on the Security Group name in the EC2 ➡ Instance details and a new screen will open. Go to **Inbound** tab in the bottom half of the screen and make sure it has a line that says:

```
| MySQL | TCP | 3306 | sg-1234abcd |
```

If it doesn't Click on **Edit** and add such a rule.

That should fix your problem.

However consider using **AWS Relational Database Service (RDS)** instead of setting up MySQL replication on EC2 instances. RDS provides a managed, high availability databases with automatic fail over, 100% compatible with MySQL. Unless you've got very very special requirements RDS is most likely a better option than managing your own MySQL cluster.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: It work now. Thank you for find my problems. I didn't consider the SG. My employer use physical machine. That is no free server for me. So I just trying to practice on my EC2.